# drone "Insufficient privileges to use privileged mode"

Tags: drone.io, gogs

i had write a .drone.yml in my gogs git repository. but when i push the git change , drone web tell me Insufficient privileges to use privileged mode. how can i fix it?

this is my .drone.yml:

```
pipeline:
   build:
     image: test-harbor.cx580.com/centos/centos7:Beat2.0
     privileged: true
     commands:
      - mkdir -p /data/k8s/drone/jar-db/
      - \cp README.md /data/k8s/drone/jar-db/
      - ls /data/k8s/drone/jar-db/
   push:
     image: plugins/docker
     repo: test-harbor.cx580.com/centos/centos7:Beat2.0
     registry: test-harbor.cx580.com
     username: ci
     password: '1qaz!QAZ'
     tags:
      - latest
```

i had search in google, this websize  tell me `Your repository isn't in the trusted list of repositories. Get in touch with Devops and ask them to trust it` but ,how can i trusted the repositorie?

and i get setting in the drone web , and check the Trusted in the settings,but it also failed : 
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcBTw.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Set drone-server env (My repositorie is GitLab)

`...
    - DRONE_OPEN=false
    - DRONE_ADMIN=<your gitlab username>
    - DRONE_GITLAB_PRIVATE_MODE=true
    ...`

2. Enable drone settings

> Settings -> Trusted [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rN07n.png)

Comment: I just found that only admin can modify "Project Settings", so the key is to set "DRONE_ADMIN".